# SQL Server : left join - check for right table column value is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, case

I have a query as follows:

```
select --this select should always give me 1 record
    tbl1.Id, tbl1.Name, tbl1.Address, tbl2.relNo, 
    CASE WHEN tbl3.Comments IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Required'
from 
    table1 tbl1 
inner join 
    table2 tbl2 on tbl2.Id = tbl1.Id
left join -- This left join table gives me 5 records for one instance
    (select 
         R.Id, C.Comments
     from
         tblC C
     inner join 
         tblR R on R.Id = C.id) tbl3 on tbl3.Id = tbl2.Id
```

I want to write a CASE statement on the rows my left join is giving to check for null value as above and my final select query always return only 1 row. Is there a way to check if all five Comments Column values from my left join be checked for NULLs in the above query?

Comment: Sum your case statement and group by your other returned values? Or use a sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a shortcut an use a COUNT() OVER PARTITION

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tbl3.Id)  =0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Required'
```

You would have to `DISTINCT` your output above. Another option would be to `GROUP BY` and filter in the `HAVING` clause.

```
select --this select should always give me 1 record
     tbl1.Id, tbl1.Name, tbl1.Address, tbl2.relNo
From table1 tbl1 
inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl2.Id = tbl1.Id
left join (-- This left join table gives me 5 records for one instance
      SELECT R.Id,
             C.Comments
      FROM tblC C
      INNER JOIN tblR R on R.Id = C.id
 ) tbl3 on tbl3.Id = tbl2.Id     
 GROUP BY 
    Id, Name, Address, relNo
 HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

**(CASE WHEN (select count(tbl3.id) FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl3.Comments IS NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as 'RequiredVal'**

```
select --this select should always give me 1 record
     tbl1.Id, tbl1.Name, tbl1.Address, tbl2.relNo, 
     CASE WHEN tbl3.Comments IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Required'

     , (CASE WHEN (select count(tbl3.id) FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl3.Comments IS NULL) then 1 else 0 end) as 'RequiredVal'

From table1 tbl1 
inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl2.Id = tbl1.Id
left join (-- This left join table gives me 5 records for one instance
      SELECT R.Id,
             C.Comments
      FROM tblC C
      INNER JOIN tblR R on R.Id = C.id
 ) tbl3 on tbl3.Id = tbl2.Id
```